# Getting Specific Data From XML Document Using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML document.Code is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nlmSearchResult>
  <term>cancer</term>
  <file>viv_iUjELT</file>
  <server>pvlbsrch16</server>
  <count>341</count>
  <retstart>0</retstart>
  <retmax>10</retmax>
  <list num="341" start="0" per="10">
    <document rank="9" url="https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/cancer.html">
      <content name="title">&lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">&lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Carcinoma&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">&lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Malignancy&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">&lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Neoplasms&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">&lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Oncology&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">&lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Tumor&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
    </document>
    <document rank="0" url="https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/throatcancer.html">
      <content name="title">Throat &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Hypopharyngeal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Laryngeal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Laryngopharyngeal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Nasopharyngeal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Oropharyngeal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Pharyngeal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
    </document>
    <document rank="1" url="https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/intestinalcancer.html">
      <content name="title">Intestinal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Gastrointestinal Stromal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Tumors&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Small Intestine &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;Cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Duodenal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Ileal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
      <content name="altTitle">Jejunal &lt;span class="qt0"&gt;&lt;span class="qt1"&gt;cancer&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</content>
    </document>
  </list>
</nlmSearchResult>
```

I am getting the names from the content tags.In this code there are three document tags while number of document tags is varying. I am getting the name="title" using this script

```
$myXMLData = file_get_contents('https://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ws/query?db=healthTopics&term=cancer');


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($myXMLData);

//Getting titles
$titles = $xml->xpath("//nlmSearchResult/list/document/content[@name='title']");
$titleCount = count($titles);
for ($j=0; $j < $titleCount; $j++) { 
    echo $xml->xpath("//nlmSearchResult/list/document/content[@name='title']")[$j].'<br />';
}

// Getting alternative titles
$alts = $xml->xpath("//nlmSearchResult/list/document/content[@name='altTitle']");
 $altCount = count($alts);
for ($i=0; $i < $altCount; $i++) { 
  echo $xml->xpath("//nlmSearchResult/list/document/content[@name='altTitle']")[$i].'<br />';
}
```

Now all the documents have different number of alternative titles so I can't get the specific length for each document. What I wanna achieve now is to get document tags wise titles.For example,
document[0]->content[@name='altTitle'] How can I achieve this? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe, you will show needed  output, because i don't understand your question

Comment: Actually The code I am using is giving me all titles in the document. But I want title and alternatives document tag wise. like in first loop I can get altTitles of first document tag and in 2nd loop it have to show me altTitle of second document tag

Comment: look that code. i hope it will help you - https://eval.in/554411

Comment: Problem solved sir @splash58
Thank you very much (y) :)